# System.Drawing Rotate DrawString

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, system.drawing

I am using `System.Drawing` to plot a bitmap and a graphic, gp. This method is working for me.

I have previously drawn a circle with `radius = 250`. As below there are 17 precalulated `angle(nn)` with text printed horizontally to the `left(far)` and to the `right(near)` depending on the 90 to 270 line.

I would like to graph the text at the point radially outward from the center starting at `radius = 250` using `gp.RotateTransform(angle(nn))` or any other method. Obviously `RotateTransform` did not produce good results.

```
Dim txtBrush As New SolidBrush(Color.Blue)
Dim hFont As New System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 10, FontStyle.Regular)
Dim format1 As New StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoClip)
Dim format2 As New StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoClip)
format1.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Far
format1.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far
format2.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near
format2.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near

For nn = 0 To 17
    If angle(nn) >= 90 And angle(nn) <= 270 Then 'gp.RotateTransform(angle(nn))
        gp.DrawString(ephemeris(angle(nn)), hFont, txtBrush, 250 * Math.Cos(angle(nn) * Pi / 180) + xCenter, -250 * Math.Sin(angle(nn) * Pi / 180) + yCenter, format1)
    Else
        gp.DrawString(ephemeris(angle(nn)), hFont, txtBrush, 250 * Math.Cos(angle(nn) * Pi / 180) + xCenter, -250 * Math.Sin(angle(nn) * Pi / 180) + yCenter, format2)
    End If
Next nn
```

Comment: Why was the result not good? Please show a screenshot.

Comment: This displays text horizontally.  I would like to display text radially.

Comment: You mean, like arranged around a circle?

Comment: Going out from the edge of the circle.